# Conditionizr V4 Issue

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to use Conditionizr V4 with a WP site, but cannot get it to function.

I have added the JS file via functions.php as below (Yes, the file is located there!):

```
    wp_register_script('conditionizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/vendor/conditionizr.js', array(), '4.3.0'); // Conditionizr
wp_enqueue_script('conditionizr'); // Enqueue it!
```

I then added this to my header.php:

```
     <?php wp_head(); ?>    
    <script>
    // conditionizr.com
    // configure environment tests
    conditionizr.config({
        assets: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/conditionizr/',
        tests: {
            'chrome':['class'],
            'ie9': ['class'],
            'ie8': ['class']
        }
    });
    conditionizr.polyfill('//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js', ['ie6', 'ie7', 'ie8']);
 </script>
</head>
```

But when I check the source code, there is no class added to the HTML tag?

Link here: http://website-test-lab.com/sites/xpect/

What am I missing out or doing wrong?! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we rebuilt Conditionizr, version 4 had a huge jump in changes and no longer packaged detects as part of the core. This way tests were more reliable and the core library was dropped to just 1KB!

First, check you're using the latest version, grab that [here](//github.com/conditionizr/conditionizr).

Second, you'll need to add these tests, but they need to be declared *above* `conditionizr.config()`:

Chrome ([source](https://github.com/conditionizr/conditionizr/blob/master/detects/chrome.js)):

```
conditionizr.add('chrome', [], function () {
  return !!window.chrome && /google/i.test(navigator.vendor);
});
```

IE9 ([source](https://github.com/conditionizr/conditionizr/blob/master/detects/ie9.js)):

```
conditionizr.add('ie9', [], function () {
  return (Function('/*@cc_on return (/^9/.test(@_jscript_version) && /MSIE 9\.0(?!.*IEMobile)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)); @*/')());
});
```

IE8 ([source](https://github.com/conditionizr/conditionizr/blob/master/detects/ie8.js)):

```
conditionizr.add('ie8', [], function () {
  return (Function('/*@cc_on return (@_jscript_version > 5.7 && !/^(9|10)/.test(@_jscript_version)); @*/')());
});
```

With version 4, you can also choose whether to use the config module for declaring what tests, or if it's easier you can add them inside the empty array, for example a `class`:

```
conditionizr.add('chrome', ['class'], function () {
  return !!window.chrome && /google/i.test(navigator.vendor);
});
```

All other detects can be found [here](https://github.com/conditionizr/conditionizr/tree/master/detects) as well as the [Docs](https://github.com/conditionizr/conditionizr/blob/master/docs/DOCS.md#conditionizr-v400-docs).

Comment: I have updated my code but now have incorrect file paths to the css and js files. Not sure why, but it appears to be leaving out the final trailing slash. (See chrome dev tools)

Comment: Another thing I noticed with this version of conditionizr is when I add the detect for IE8, the .ie8 class doesn't show whilst testing on IE10 > F12 Developer Tools.